# How can I maintain collapsible item position?

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, bootstrap-4

I'm having a problem with a listing of items inside collapsible cards, this happens:

[image]

I wanted it to look like this:

[image]

Is it possible to do as desired using the Bootstrap's Grid Layout or Flex Layout?

My code example ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/58uLg0pc/))

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="card col-12 col-md-4">
            <div id="accordion-1">
                <div class="card-header" id="heading-1">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-1">
                            Collapsible #1
                        </button>
                    </h5>
                </div>

                <div id="collapse-1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading-1" data-parent="#accordion-1">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card col-12 col-md-4">
            <div id="accordion-2">
                <div class="card-header" id="heading-2">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-2">
                            Collapsible #2
                        </button>
                    </h5>
                </div>

                <div id="collapse-2" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading-2" data-parent="#accordion-2">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
        
        <div class="card col-12 col-md-4">
            <div id="accordion-3">
                <div class="card-header" id="heading-3">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-3" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-3">
                            Collapsible #3
                        </button>
                    </h5>
                </div>

                <div id="collapse-3" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading-3" data-parent="#accordion-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>   
                    
        <div class="card col-12 col-md-4">
            <div id="accordion-4">
                <div class="card-header" id="heading-4">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-4" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-4">
                            Collapsible #4
                        </button>
                    </h5>
                </div>

                <div id="collapse-4" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading-4" data-parent="#accordion-4">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>   
        
        <div class="card col-12 col-md-4">
            <div id="accordion-5">
                <div class="card-header" id="heading-5">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-5" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-5">
                            Collapsible #5
                        </button>
                    </h5>
                </div>

                <div id="collapse-5" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading-5" data-parent="#accordion-5">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                      
    </div>
</div>
```

I appreciate anyone who can help :)

Comment: You should have voted up answers that were helpful. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make up 3 columns and have those cards piled up on each column, instead of putting each card on its own column:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="card">#1</div>
        <div class="card">#4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="card">#2</div>
        <div class="card">#5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="card">#3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/w3t2qvzs/4/

Answer (score 1):

You need to create 3 columns and put the lines inside them

example here: https://jsfiddle.net/ishnechmad/b94a8xnp/2/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="accordion-1" class="col">
            <div class="card-header" id="heading-1">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-1">
                                Collapsible #1
                    </button>
                </h5>
            </div>

            <div id="collapse-1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading-1" data-parent="#accordion-1">
                <div class="card-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="accordion-2" class="col">
                    <div class="card-header" id="heading-2">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-2">
                                Collapsible #2
                            </button>
                        </h5>
                    </div>

                    <div id="collapse-2" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading-2" data-parent="#accordion-2">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card col-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="accordion-3" class="col">
                    <div class="card-header" id="heading-3">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-3" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-3">
                                Collapsible #3
                            </button>
                        </h5>
                    </div>

                    <div id="collapse-3" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading-3" data-parent="#accordion-3">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="accordion-4" class="col">
                    <div class="card-header" id="heading-4">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-4" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-4">
                                Collapsible #4
                            </button>
                        </h5>
                    </div>

                    <div id="collapse-4" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading-4" data-parent="#accordion-4">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card col-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="accordion-5" class="col">
                    <div class="card-header" id="heading-5">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-5" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-5">
                                Collapsible #5
                            </button>
                        </h5>
                    </div>

                    <div id="collapse-5" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading-5" data-parent="#accordion-5">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's rarely a good idea to combine your layout elements with your content elements. Separate them and it's all fine:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-4">
  <div class="card">
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/58uLg0pc/9/)

Comment: got it, but expanding collapsible 1 still "pushes" collapsible 5 together with collapsible 4